# How do I better debug this Intermittent / Indeterministic Python Segmentation Fault?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, paramiko

Warning: this is long and I can't fathom anybody volunteering their time for this but I really need to fix this bug.  I'm going to try to provide as much information as possible and I would immensely appreciate any lead on where I should go to debug this.  I understand it's infinitely more complicated when you can't see the entire source so I apologize, but this bug has been driving me up the wall for 2 days now.

This **only happens approximately 1 in 7 times** while running (can't repeat every time)

> ```
> (gdb) run GUI.py
> Starting program: /usr/bin/python2.7 GUI.py
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
> Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
> [New Thread 0x7ffff4947700 (LWP 4868)]
> [New Thread 0x7fffef655700 (LWP 4870)]
> [New Thread 0x7fffeee54700 (LWP 4872)]
> [Thread 0x7fffeee54700 (LWP 4872) exited]
> [New Thread 0x7fffeee54700 (LWP 4874)]
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007ffff68b416d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libtk8.6.so
> (gdb) info threads
>   Id   Target Id         Frame 
>   5    Thread 0x7fffeee54700 (LWP 4874) "python2.7" 0x00007ffff781c0af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
>    from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
>   3    Thread 0x7fffef655700 (LWP 4870) "python2.7" 0x00007ffff754006d in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>   2    Thread 0x7ffff4947700 (LWP 4868) "python2.7" 0x00007ffff7541e43 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> * 1    Thread 0x7ffff7fd1700 (LWP 4867) "python2.7" 0x00007ffff68b416d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libtk8.6.so
> (gdb) l
> 1 ../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S: No such file or directory.
> (gdb) backtrace 
> #0  0x00007ffff68b416d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libtk8.6.so
> #1  0x00007ffff6553ce6 in TclServiceIdle () from /usr/lib64/libtcl8.6.so
> #2  0x00007ffff6534d0d in Tcl_DoOneEvent () from /usr/lib64/libtcl8.6.so
> #3  0x00007ffff6b4ede0 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
> #4  0x00007ffff7af5bc3 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #5  0x00007ffff7afbae6 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #6  0x00007ffff7af55d3 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #7  0x00007ffff7af732c in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #8  0x00007ffff7afbae6 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #9  0x00007ffff7b28802 in PyEval_EvalCode () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #10 0x00007ffff7b34f6d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #11 0x00007ffff7ac3005 in PyRun_FileExFlags () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #12 0x00007ffff7ac3be4 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #13 0x00007ffff7acb813 in Py_Main () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
> #14 0x00007ffff7483be5 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #15 0x0000000000400791 in _start ()
> ```

My code is 2,500+ lines so I have cut as much as possible to explain what's happening. I've omitted init parts, so please disregard any syntax errors that are from the cut.

```
class SSH:
        # Function call can specify if stdout/err is to be omitted
    def sshRunCommand(self, command, print_stdout=True, print_stderr=True):

        # Appends command to always change to the home directory first
        x = "cd /home/" + self.username + "/; " + command

        # Locally output an terminal-esque command look-a-like
        if print_stdout:
            print self.username + "@" + self.payloadd + ":" + x

        # Execute the command storing input/output to local variables
        try:
            (stdin, stdout, stderr) = self.client.exec_command(x)
        except Exception as e:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", e)
            return ([], [])
        return (stdout, stderr)

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ssh_session = SSH()

    def uploadThreadStart(self):
        global q

        # Code here just SFTPs file, never causes error


        # If user wants to load image into local registry, do so.
        try:
            if tkMessageBox.askyesno("Load Image?",
            "Would you like to load the image on remote PC?"):
                q.put("sftp.load")
                self.ssh_session.sshRunCommand(
                    "docker load --input " +
                    os.path.basename(self.m_file.name),
                    True, True)
                print "Successfully loaded image " + self.m_file.name
            q.put("sftp.complete")
        except Exception as e:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", e)

    # Function call for actually uploading Container
    def uploadDockerImagePopupWindowButtonPressed(self):
        global sftp_thread
        global q

        # Start the thread
        if self.m_file:
            q.put("sftp.start")
            sftp_thread = Thread(
                target=self.uploadThreadStart,
                args=())
            sftp_thread.daemon = True
            sftp_thread.start()
        return
```

It's very simple: the GUI is the main thread where if I press a button, a new thread is launched where a file in an entry field (ex. `/home/user/file.tar`) is assigned to `self.m_file` and sftp's over.  Paramiko seems to always spawn a separate thread to do this (from gdb output).  Then I'm prompted to use Paramiko to run `exec_command` if they want to "load" the file they just transferred. I always preface with a `cd /home/user/`.  I'm led to believe that because the print statement in `sshRunCommand` doesn't show, that the segmentation fault occurs around the `exec_command.`

Is there anything glaring from here or a lead to pursue to fix this?  With the multithreads it seems like a race condition but I'm extremely unsure.  If you read this or even skimmed it, I greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: You text above doesn't show any print output from your code. Did any of your code print anything? Add a print before and after the message box so the console has a log of that. This is likely a bug in python itself though, so you may need to get symbols+source for python and tk to better understand whats going wrong. Often the best way to debug complex threading problems is via printf. Add plenty of prints (to a log file, flushing each print). Since logging affects timing, it may change your crash frequency too.

Comment: Adding print statements or delay statements to try to pin point which line of code does it causes the program to not do it anymore, almost like a fix.  So for now I'm just leaving in a 1 second sleep before and after it and I can't recreate it.  I didn't want it to be like this but I really have to move on.